# Microsoft update site has no SSL

Tags: https, links, microsoft

We need to put a link to Microsoft update site. But we come from SSL and Microsoft has no SSL activated for their update site.

Is there any common workaround?

Comment: What do you mean by "a link"? A simple `<a href="https://windowsupdate.microsoft.com/">` or something more complex?

Comment: Go to this site, you will receive an SSL error.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What is it you are trying to achieve? Why can't you simply link to `<a href="http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com/">`?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to link to the Microsoft update site. It's not intended/designed to be directly accessed from a regular browser. That's why it uses a MS-issued SSL certificate.

Comment: It's all gateway to activate a secure method of transfer behind the scenes. You'll need to take up your problem with Microsoft as it is a website issue, not a browser client issue. After working your way through, on Windows 7 and later, you are told to do updates from your start menu. Since XP will be dead after April 2014, trying to get there is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

If you are placing link to non-secure page from secure page; browser will show warning message for sure. As far as I know, you will have to find secure source of this link or you can do this by placing JavaScript that redirect to this Microsoft HTTP page (I did not tried it but I think it should work).

Comment: That's what I want to achieve :-) There is no secure page from microsoft for updates!

Comment: Just had an idea to implement this..Create one url on your website. i.e: yourwebsite.com/1234.html. Now 301 redirect this page to microsoft page. now in your coding, place link of your website yourwebsite.com/1234.html (which is https page) and when someone click on it, he will be redirect to microsoft website.